# Cannot find id and update and increment sub-document - returns null Mongoose/mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, increment

I have a problem where I cannot seem to retrieve the _id of my nested objects in my array. Specifically the foods part of my object array. I want to find the _id, of lets say risotto, and then increment the orders count dynamically (from that same object).

I'm trying to get this done dynamically as I have tried the Risotto id in the req.body._id and thats fine but i can't go forward and try to increment orders as i get null.

I keep getting null for some reason and I think its a nested document but im not sure. heres my route file and schema too.

```
router.patch("/update", [auth], async (req, res) => {


const orderPlus = await MenuSchema.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: '5e3b75f2a3d43821a0fb57f0' }, { $inc: {  "food.0.orders": 1 }}, {new: true} );
//want to increment orders dynamically once id is found
//not sure how as its in its own seperate index in an array object

  try {
    res.status(200).send(orderPlus);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});
```

Schema:

```
const FoodSchema = new Schema({
  foodname: String,
  orders: Number,
});

const MenuSchema = new Schema({
  menuname: String,
  menu_register: Number,
  foods: [FoodSchema]
});
```

Heres the returned Database JSON

```
{
    "_id": "5e3b75f2a3d43821a0fb57ee",
    "menuname": "main course",
    "menu_register": 49,
    "foods": [
        {
            "_id": "5e3b75f2a3d43821a0fb57f0",
            "foodname": "Risotto",
            "orders": 37
        },
        {
            "_id": "5e3b75f2a3d43821a0fb57ef",
            "foodname": "Tiramisu",
            "orders": 11
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

the id for the menuname works in its place but i dont need that as i need to access the foods subdocs. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending food id (`5e3b75f2a3d43821a0fb57f0`) to the MenuSchema.findByIdAndUpdate update query. It should be the menu id which is `5e3b75f2a3d43821a0fb57ee`

You can find a menu by it's id, and update it's one of the foods by using food _id or foodname using [mongodb $ positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#update-nested-arrays-in-conjunction-with-identifier).

Update by giving menu id and food id:

```js
router.patch("/update", [auth], async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const orderPlus = await MenuSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(
      "5e3b75f2a3d43821a0fb57ee",
      { $inc: { "foods.$[inner].orders": 1 } },
      { arrayFilters: [{ "inner._id": "5e3b75f2a3d43821a0fb57f0" }], new: true }
    );

    res.status(200).send(orderPlus);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});
```

Update by giving menu id and foodname:

```js
router.patch("/update", [auth], async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const orderPlus = await MenuSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(
      "5e3b75f2a3d43821a0fb57ee",
      { $inc: { "foods.$[inner].orders": 1 } },
      { arrayFilters: [{ "inner.foodname": "Risotto" }], new: true }
    );

    res.status(200).send(orderPlus);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: You sir are a Genius! This worked flawlessly. Thank you so much!